# Display language switcher button shortcode of WPGlobus plugin - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, multiple-languages

I am using WPGlobus plugin to make website multi-language. A widget is displaying in widget area but I want to add language switcher button manually. 
I search its short code to display language switcher flags. But not found any any shortcode. 
Any best way to display buttons manually by shortcode.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code on your wordpress theme . I hope will help you!

```
<?php the_widget( 'WPGlobusWidget' ); ?>
```